# should the sample be homogenous for developing a tool supposed to be generalized across 4 countries??

Tags: normality-assumption

I am planning to develop a new tool and planning to use it across 4 countries. For the tool validation, is it right to include sample from very large population of 4 countries? Will it affect the normality of the distribution of data and tamper the data analysis process?

Is it important that the sample need to be homogeneous for applying factor analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate a tool on samples similar to the population you want to use it on.

Whether you need to use 4 separate samples would depend on the nature of the tool and whether there is some reason to suspect that its validity might vary across the 4 countries. It might be possible to combine all 4 countries' samples into 1 sample. It might not.

The normality of the measure may be affected or not; again depending on the nature of the measure and the countries.  For example, let's say you collected data on height of adult males. In any one country, this is going to be close to normally distributed. If the 4 countries are (say) Sweden, Denmark, Finland and Iceland, then the 4 distributions are likely to be quite similar. On the other hand, if the 4 countries are (say) Indonesia, Gambia, Canada and the Netherlands, you may run into problems ([Height by country data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height))

However, even in cases where the distributions are different, the factor structure may be similar (or not).

What is your measure designed to do, and what countries are you looking at?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply sir. I am planning to develop a new tool on "Employability". . in countries like India, Singapore , Malaysia and few Asian Countries

Comment: OK, so, the question of whether you need four samples hinges on whether "employability" is likely to be different in these countries. Doubtless you know more about how to answer this than I do.